# How to refresh the page after routing to that page on click of a button from previous page

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have 2 pages, one home and page2. when I click a button on home page it is routing to page2. Now after clicking the button on home,when I comes to page2 it should be refresh,since there is some cache issue in my project. I added the window.location.reload() on ngoninit,but here my page is continuously refreshing.
Here is the code below.

### home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  template: '<button (click)="gonextPage()">Go to next page</button>',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
imageSource :any;
statusdata1: any;
moreThanTen:boolean = false;
showit:boolean = false;
groupList:any = [];

constructor(private router: Router) { }
gonextPage(){
this.router.navigateByUrl('/page2');    
}
  ngOnInit() {
     // window.location.reload();
    /* First data */
    let response = 
    {"vehicle_number":1,"vehicle_name":"car","status":"yellow"}
    let response1 = {"vehicle_number":0,"vehicle_name":"car","status":"yellow"}
    let response2 = {"vehicle_number":2,"vehicle_name":"car","status":"yellow"}
    this.groupList.push(response,response1,response2);
    console.log(this.groupList);




  }

}
```

### page2.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-page2',
  template: '',
  styleUrls: ['./page2.component.css']
})

export class page2Component implements OnInit {
imageSource :any;
statusdata1: any;
moreThanTen:boolean = false;
showit:boolean = false;
groupList:any = [];

constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     window.location.reload();
    /* First data */
    let response = 
    {"vehicle_number":1,"vehicle_name":"car","status":"yellow"}
    let response1 = {"vehicle_number":0,"vehicle_name":"car","status":"yellow"}
    let response2 = {"vehicle_number":2,"vehicle_name":"car","status":"yellow"}
    this.groupList.push(response,response1,response2);
    console.log(this.groupList);




  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remove the previous edited answer because it is bullied.
The only way is to use an information that persists even when reloading the js (on window.location.reload();), because all the rest of the information would be lost. You can use the localStorage (with localStorage.setItem('firstReload', 'true'); ).

```
  ngOnInit() {
    if (!localStorage.getItem('firstReload') || localStorage.getItem('firstReload') == 'true') {
      localStorage.setItem('firstReload', 'false');
      window.location.reload();
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem('firstReload', 'true');
    }
  }
```

Here a working modified example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-correct-routing?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpage.component.ts

Comment: Thanks for your answer, first time not refreshing.

Comment: True, I made a small correction to make it work even on the first try. To test it, remove the "firstReload" key from the "localStorage".

Comment: If my answer has been useful to you, vote it, please.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to manually reload. If you route to a specific component always you will get a new component. If you can explain more about ur problem I can help you.