# How to prevent continuously refreshing the page in angular using window.location

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a simple page in angular, I need it to be manually refresh at the time of onload due to some requirement in my project. I have added a code and its working properly but refreshing hte page continously. I need to prevent here to refresh continueosly. Here is the code below.

### home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  template: '<button (click)="gonextPage()">Go to next page</button>',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
     window.location.reload();
    /* First data */
    console.log('hello');
  }

}
```

Comment: but what do you use window.location for? and don't use routing?

Comment: This isn't a very "Angular" approach (or SPA approach in general). You should get and set the query params using the active route and router.

Comment: and stop using var

Comment: you have a lot of syntax problems, array is not a map

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to refresh the page after routing to that page on click of a button from previous page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61564292/how-to-refresh-the-page-after-routing-to-that-page-on-click-of-a-button-from-pre)

Comment: ngOnInit is called every time a component is instantiated, that's why it refresh continuously

Comment: I need to prevent it,it should  refresh only once when page load

Comment: I have cleaned the code now you won't get sytax problem

Comment: Why do you need to refresh the page? What is the reason behind it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why do you want to refresh the page.

But what happens in your case is

First time `app-home` initializes and page gets refreshed. Again after page reload `app-home` initializes and page gets refreshed and so on.

So to prevent you have yo include a hacky solution. Which will obviously fail in some cases.

Solution is

```
ngOnInit() {
   if (!sessionStorage.getItem('isPageRefreshed')) { 
       sessionStorage.setItem('isPageRefreshed', 'true');
      // This will reload page once prevent reloading of page again for that session. 
       window.location.reload();

   }
 }
```

Comment: @aepifano also  your answer is not suitable for this question. As the OP wants to reload the page in a session. by following your answer, the page won't ever gets refreshed in future after one refresh

Answer (score 0):

I still think this is a duplicate question anyway...
Try this solution:

```
if (!localStorage.getItem('firstReload') || localStorage.getItem('firstReload') == 'true') {
  localStorage.setItem('firstReload', 'false');
  window.location.reload();
} else {
  localStorage.setItem('firstReload', 'true');
}
```

This is a working example:
[https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-correct-routing?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpage.component.ts](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-correct-routing?file=src/app/page.component.ts)

It works both by clicking on the link from the home page and by refreshing the page.